# Idle face direction/ new unity input system/ Unity 2D

Tags: unity3d

Посоветуйте, что нужно использовать в коде для определения вектора движения спрайта?

Например у меня есть анимированный спрайт и он двигается по полю следующим образом:

```
void Update()
{
    rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(playerPositionX * moveSpeed, playerPositionY * moveSpeed);
    SetAnimationMovementDirrection();
} 

public void Move(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    playerPositionX = context.ReadValue<Vector2>().x;
    playerPositionY = context.ReadValue<Vector2>().y;
}
void SetAnimationMovementDirrection()                 
{
    playerAnimator.SetFloat("movementX", rigidBody.velocity.x);
    playerAnimator.SetFloat("movementY", rigidBody.velocity.y);
}
```

Как получить направление его движения, чтобы я мог присвоить этим значениям Idle анимацию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно в коде держат свойство, что-то типа

```
bool facedRight = false
```

И опираются на неё.

И нужно менять её значение в зависимости от того куда было движение по оси X (`Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")`)

Уже на основе этой переменной можно ориентироваться.

---

Вместо `right`/`left` можно использовать соответственно `facedForward`/`facedBackward`, чтобы небыло некоторой непонятки.

---

А можно сразу по дефолту задать направление вперёд и сделать метод `flip` который просто будет зеркально отражать спрайт по оси `x`, то есть просто умножать на `-1`

Comment: А разве axisName не относится к старому input manager-у? Я к тому, что если брать (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")), то можно все управление от него построить и вообще не использовать новый input manager. В чем тогда смысл?

Comment: Если бы я понял всё то, что ты написал в комментарии - было бы замечательно.

Comment: Если тебе удобно везде ориентироваться на код `if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 1)` вместо `facedForward` - окей

Comment: Я пока безграмотный. Если попонятнее, то в случае использования (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")) вместо 

void Update()
{
    rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(playerPositionX * moveSpeed, playerPositionY * moveSpeed);
} 

Можно написать 
void Update()
{
    float horizontal = input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")
    float vertical = input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")
    rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical );
} 
и не париться с методом Move в моем коде и Input System Package в самом юнити. Это и короче будет и направления для айдла я легко получу.

Comment: Это вообще перперндикулярные вещи. Axis возвращает значение не больше -1 или 1. А тебе же надо куда-то двигаться? -1 0 1 для определения стороны движения. А мягкое регулярование изменения координат происходит за счёт остальных параметров.........плюс наименование переменной например facedForward  всегда будет говорить о том, что в ней, и в любом участке кода в 10000 строк ты поймёшь о чём речь.....при этом встретив на 8345-ой строке  линию в виде `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 1` будешь долго сидеть думать для чего это)